# Многошаговая форма регистрации запоминает шаг

Tags: javascript, html, форма, регистрация

Имеется форма регистрации и JS который выполняет шаги. Уважаемое сообщество, прошу помощи. Необходимо чтобы после закрытия форма помнила шаг (с данными формы разобрался)

```js
//jQuery time
var current_fs, next_fs, previous_fs; //fieldsets
var left, opacity, scale; //fieldset properties which we will animate
var animating; //flag to prevent quick multi-click glitches

$(".next").click(function() {
  if (animating) return false;
  animating = true;

  current_fs = $(this).parent();
  next_fs = $(this).parent().next();

  //activate next step on progressbar using the index of next_fs
  $("#progressbar li").eq($("fieldset").index(next_fs)).addClass("active");

  //show the next fieldset
  next_fs.show();
  //hide the current fieldset with style
  current_fs.animate({
    opacity: 0
  }, {
    step: function(now, mx) {
      //as the opacity of current_fs reduces to 0 - stored in "now"
      //1. scale current_fs down to 80%
      scale = 1 - (1 - now) * 0.2;
      //2. bring next_fs from the right(50%)
      left = (now * 50) + "%";
      //3. increase opacity of next_fs to 1 as it moves in
      opacity = 1 - now;
      current_fs.css({
        'transform': 'scale(' + scale + ')',
        'position': 'absolute'
      });
      next_fs.css({
        'left': left,
        'opacity': opacity
      });
    },
    duration: 800,
    complete: function() {
      current_fs.hide();
      animating = false;
    },
    //this comes from the custom easing plugin
    easing: 'easeInOutBack'
  });
});

$(".previous").click(function() {
  if (animating) return false;
  animating = true;

  current_fs = $(this).parent();
  previous_fs = $(this).parent().prev();

  //de-activate current step on progressbar
  $("#progressbar li").eq($("fieldset").index(current_fs)).removeClass("active");

  //show the previous fieldset
  previous_fs.show();
  //hide the current fieldset with style
  current_fs.animate({
    opacity: 0
  }, {
    step: function(now, mx) {
      //as the opacity of current_fs reduces to 0 - stored in "now"
      //1. scale previous_fs from 80% to 100%
      scale = 0.8 + (1 - now) * 0.2;
      //2. take current_fs to the right(50%) - from 0%
      left = ((1 - now) * 50) + "%";
      //3. increase opacity of previous_fs to 1 as it moves in
      opacity = 1 - now;
      current_fs.css({
        'left': left
      });
      previous_fs.css({
        'transform': 'scale(' + scale + ')',
        'opacity': opacity
      });
    },
    duration: 800,
    complete: function() {
      current_fs.hide();
      animating = false;
    },
    //this comes from the custom easing plugin
    easing: 'easeInOutBack'
  });


});

var elements = document.querySelectorAll('input, textarea');

for (i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
  (function(element) {
    var id = element.getAttribute('id');
    element.value = localStorage.getItem(id);
    element.oninput = function() {
      localStorage.setItem(id, element.value);
    };
  })(elements[i]);
}
```

```css
/*custom font*/

@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat);

/*basic reset*/

* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

html {
  height: 100%;
  background: #6441A5;
  /* fallback for old browsers */
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(to left, #6441A5, #2a0845);
  /* Chrome 10-25, Safari 5.1-6 */
}

body {
  font-family: montserrat, arial, verdana;
  background: transparent;
}


/*form styles*/

#msform {
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
  margin-top: 30px;
}

#msform fieldset {
  background: white;
  border: 0 none;
  border-radius: 0px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 15px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
  padding: 20px 30px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  width: 80%;
  margin: 0 10%;
  /*stacking fieldsets above each other*/
  position: relative;
}


/*Hide all except first fieldset*/

#msform fieldset:not(:first-of-type) {
  display: none;
}


/*inputs*/

#msform input,
#msform textarea {
  padding: 15px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-radius: 0px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  width: 100%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-family: montserrat;
  color: #2C3E50;
  font-size: 13px;
}

#msform input:focus,
#msform textarea:focus {
  -moz-box-shadow: none !important;
  -webkit-box-shadow: none !important;
  box-shadow: none !important;
  border: 1px solid #ee0979;
  outline-width: 0;
  transition: All 0.5s ease-in;
  -webkit-transition: All 0.5s ease-in;
  -moz-transition: All 0.5s ease-in;
  -o-transition: All 0.5s ease-in;
}


/*buttons*/

#msform .action-button {
  width: 100px;
  background: #ee0979;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: white;
  border: 0 none;
  border-radius: 25px;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 10px 5px;
  margin: 10px 5px;
}

#msform .action-button:hover,
#msform .action-button:focus {
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 2px white, 0 0 0 3px #ee0979;
}

#msform .action-button-previous {
  width: 100px;
  background: #C5C5F1;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: white;
  border: 0 none;
  border-radius: 25px;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 10px 5px;
  margin: 10px 5px;
}

#msform .action-button-previous:hover,
#msform .action-button-previous:focus {
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 2px white, 0 0 0 3px #C5C5F1;
}


/* mainheadings*/

.fs-main-title {
  font-size: 30px;
  /*    text-transform: uppercase;*/
  color: #FFF;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  letter-spacing: 2px;
  font-weight: bold;
}


/*headings*/

.fs-title {
  font-size: 18px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: #2C3E50;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  letter-spacing: 2px;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.fs-subtitle {
  font-weight: normal;
  font-size: 13px;
  color: #666;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}


/*progressbar*/

#progressbar {
  margin-bottom: 30px;
  overflow: hidden;
  /*CSS counters to number the steps*/
  counter-reset: step;
}

#progressbar li {
  list-style-type: none;
  color: white;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 9px;
  width: 33.33%;
  float: left;
  position: relative;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
}

#progressbar li:before {
  content: counter(step);
  counter-increment: step;
  width: 24px;
  height: 24px;
  line-height: 26px;
  display: block;
  font-size: 12px;
  color: #333;
  background: white;
  border-radius: 25px;
  margin: 0 auto 10px auto;
}


/*progressbar connectors*/

#progressbar li:after {
  content: '';
  width: 100%;
  height: 2px;
  background: white;
  position: absolute;
  left: -50%;
  top: 9px;
  z-index: -1;
  /*put it behind the numbers*/
}

#progressbar li:first-child:after {
  /*connector not needed before the first step*/
  content: none;
}


/*marking active/completed steps green*/


/*The number of the step and the connector before it = green*/

#progressbar li.active:before,
#progressbar li.active:after {
  background: #ee0979;
  color: white;
}


/* Not relevant to this form */

.dme_link {
  margin-top: 30px;
  text-align: center;
}

.dme_link a {
  background: #FFF;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #ee0979;
  border: 0 none;
  border-radius: 25px;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 5px 25px;
  font-size: 12px;
}

.dme_link a:hover,
.dme_link a:focus {
  background: #C5C5F1;
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>smo1in||registration Form</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

  <link rel='stylesheet prefetch' href='https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css'>

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">

  <link rel="shortcut icon" href="favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon">
  <link rel="icon" href="favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon">


</head>

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <h1 class="span12 fs-main-title text-center">smo1in</h1>
    <h2 class="span12 fs-title text-center" style="color: red">Registration Form</h2>
  </div>
  <!-- MultiStep Form -->
  <div class="row">
    <div class="container">
      <form id="msform" action="submit.php" method="post">
        <!-- progressbar -->
        <ul id="progressbar">
          <li class="active">Personal Details</li>
          <li>Adress Details</li>
          <li>Comment</li>
        </ul>
        <!-- fieldsets -->
        <fieldset>
          <h2 class="fs-title">Personal Details</h2>
          <h3 class="fs-subtitle">Tell us about you</h3>
          <input type="text" id="first_name" placeholder="Your First Name" required="" />
          <input type="text" id="second_name" placeholder="Your Second Name" required="" />
          <input type="text" id="phone" placeholder="Phone" required="" />
          <button type="button" name="next" class="next action-button">NEXT</button>
        </fieldset>
        <fieldset>
          <h2 class="fs-title">Adress Details</h2>
          <h3 class="fs-subtitle">Enter Your Address</h3>
          <input type="text" id="street" placeholder="Street" required="" />
          <input type="text" id="building" placeholder="Building №" required="" />
          <input type="text" id="city" placeholder="City" required="" />
          <button type="button" name="previous" class="previous action-button-previous">PREVIOUS</button>
          <button type="button" name="next" class="next action-button">NEXT</button>
        </fieldset>
        <fieldset>
          <h2 class="fs-title">Comment</h2>
          <h3 class="fs-subtitle">Fill in your comment</h3>
          <textarea id="comment" placeholder="Comments"></textarea>
          <button type="button" name="previous" class="previous action-button-previous">PREVIOUS</button>
          <button type="submit" name="submit" class="submit action-button">SUMBIT</button>
        </fieldset>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!-- /.MultiStep Form -->
  <script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js'></script>
  <script src='https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js'></script>
  <script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-easing/1.4.1/jquery.easing.min.js'></script>


  <script src="js/index.js"></script>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Вам поможет localstorage https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage

Comment: спасибо за подсказку,в local storage пишутся данные формы

Comment: Все что Вам угодно туда пишется и оттуда читается когда Вам надо, только объекты надо сериализовать десериализовать при помощи `JSON.stringify` `JSON.parse`